# Boost multiarray vs OpenCV Mat

Tags: opencv, boost

What is the big difference between Boost multidimensional array and OpenCV multidimensional array?

I'm implementing a clustering algorithm in C++, and need a data stuctures to store data points. It should be able to handle different dimension data, such as 1D data( gray scale image), 3D data(color images), and N-d data(after feature selection).

Which one should I choose? It seems that for OpenCV Mat, we need to know dimension of data before hand.

Comment: If you're going to use opencv functions, Mat should be better, if you will use more boost functionality, you should go with boost. 
I'd go with the library I am more experienced in.

Comment: But for Mat openCV, you must predefine the number of channels. There's no way to have one single function that can take 1-D, 3-D, or N-D data right?

Answer (score 1):

As perfanoff said, I would choose the library you are most confident in and which you are going to use more in your code. That aside, and given that you are handling image data, OpenCV seems like the better choice.

OpenCV Mat containers can return their [type](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-type), so your functions can check if matrices  have 1 channel, 3 channel or N-d data. You can also use the [element size](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-elemsize) functions to find the number of channels.

As a disclaimer, I don't have much experience with Boost multidimensional arrays.